# For an arbitrary vertex in an arbitrary polygon how to determine which of the vertex's angles lies inside the polygon knowing only the coordinates?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, polygons

Could someone explain to me how to do what the title states?

> For an arbitrary vertex in an arbitrary polygon how to determine which
> of the vertex's 2 angles lies inside the polygon knowing only the
> vertices' coordinates?

- the dimension is 2d, i.e. the polygon lies on the XY plane. There is no problem to add a dimension, if necessary
- I know all the coordinates of the vertices.

My problem is that the polygon may be very arbitrary, e.g. like the below one, and **how do I know which of the 2 angles lies inside the polygon** (the blue one or the green one)?

[image: arbitrary polygon example and the problem illustration]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of the vertices taken clockwise (for instance):
$$
(V_1, V_2, \dots, V_n)
$$
then you must take $\alpha_k=\angle V_{k-1}V_kV_{k+1}$ so that side $V_{k-1}V_k$ is carried to side $V_kV_{k+1}$ by a counter-clockwise rotation of $\alpha_k$.

In practice, that means that if $(V_{k-1}-V_k)\times(V_{k+1}-V_k)>0$ then you must take $\alpha_k<180°$, if $(V_{k-1}-V_k)\times(V_{k+1}-V_k)<0$ then you must take $\alpha_k>180°$, where:

$$
u\times v=\det\pmatrix{u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y}.
$$

Comment: the problem is that I don't know the order of vertices. In can be both: counter- and clockwise

Comment: In practice I solved this by taking a point on the bisect of the angle at 0.000001 and checked if it's inside the polygon. In my case it will work reliably